# 18.04: Does os-prober work well for kernel v5?

Tags: grub2, kernel, os-prober

[os-prober](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/os-prober) on an Ubuntu 18 instance using the Google Compute Engine *(image: ubuntu-minimal-1804-bionic-v20200220 - "Canonical, Ubuntu, 18.04 LTS Minimal, amd64 bionic minimal image built on 2020-02-20")* returns an unexpected partition:

```
# os-prober
/dev/sda1:Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (18.04):Ubuntu:linux
# uname -a
Linux pfuntner-gcp-ubuntu1804 5.0.0-1031-gcp #32-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 11 03:55:48 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
# mount
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=1885000k,nr_inodes=471250,mode=755)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=28,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=10640)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda15 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_8592.snap on /snap/core/8592 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/google-cloud-sdk_118.snap on /snap/google-cloud-sdk/118 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
lxcfs on /var/lib/lxcfs type fuse.lxcfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/1008 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=377836k,mode=700,uid=1008,gid=1009)
#
```

The output from [os-prober](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/os-prober) causes a problem when I try to modify the boot parameters and run `update-grub` because not all `linux` statements in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` have the options I'm trying to introduce.  I know `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` is generating the extra `linux` statements and that I can use `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER` to disable using the script but I don't think I should have to do that.

Google Support confirms that multiple OS's are not possible with an GCE instance and I don't expect [os-prober](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/os-prober) to return any output.